Stop Serilog from logging HTTP GET in ASP.NET Core MVC
Serilog is successfully logging but it is logging HTTP GET api calls automatically. How can the HTTP calls be suppressed?
I have entries like this in the log file:
2024-10-25 06:24:10.040 -04:00 [INF] HTTP GET / responded 200 in 6107.3816 ms

program.cs:
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
{
    var requestLoggingOptions = new RequestLoggingOptions();
    configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
});

appsettings.json:
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Override": {
            "Microsoft": "Warning", //If the error starts with Microsoft, it needs to be a warning level
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning", 
            "System": "Warning" //If the error starts with System, it needs to be a warning level
            "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"  //probably not necessary because of the line above
        }
    },
    "WriteTo": [ ... suppressed ...
    ],

    "Filter": [
        {
            "Name": "ByExcludingOnly",
            "Args": {
                "expression": "e.Request.Method == \"GET\"",
            }
        }
    ]
},

I have tried adding other minimum levels and filters but the HTTP GET records are still created.

Could you pls try "expression": "RequestMethod = 'GET'" and test again? I followed this section which shared an expression  "expression": "RequestPath like '/health%'"

You don't have "Serilog.Expressions" in "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Expressions" ],

@TinyWang When I add "Serilog.Expression" into the Using section, I get an error in program.cs 'Could not load file or assembly 'Serilog.Expression... The system cannot find the file specified.  The package is added and 'using Serilog.Expressions;' is greyed out / unused at the top of program.cs.

Just like what you can see in that github link, it requires you to install Serilog.Expressions... May I know whether you've installed this nuget?

based on my test till now, I could only say, "expression": "RequestPath like '/health%'" could work, and "expression": "StatusCode in [200, 304]" could work. But "expression": "RequestMethod = 'GET'" hasn't worked. I'm not very sure, but I think you might deserve to have a try in your side.

Yes, I did install Serilog.Expressions but it make no difference.  It  seems like you are on to something because it appears that the expressions are being ignored.

thank you for your confirmation. I hasn't worked it out, and I'm afraid there's no builtin configuration for your requirement. The rest shall be creating custom middleware. But it might bring much more work.

In your Program.cs or a similar location, you'll have a call to UseSerilogRequestLogging(). One solution to this is to assign API requests a lower logging level directly:
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(options =>
    options.GetLevel = (HttpContext ctx, double elapsed, Exception? ex) =>
        ex != null
            ? LogEventLevel.Error
            : ctx.Request.Method == "GET"
                ? LogEventLevel.Debug
                : ctx.Response.StatusCode > 499
                    ? LogEventLevel.Error
                    : LogEventLevel.Information);

(Serilog.Expressions is another good option, as mentioned by a commenter above.)

The UseSerilogRequestLogging was initially commented.  I tried the suggestion and the logging doubled and changed the INF to DBG
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging COMMENTED
2024-10-26 09:15:45.034 -04:00 [INF] HTTP GET / responded 200 in 5980.8021 ms
Inserting the suggested code
2024-10-26 09:19:54.496 -04:00 [DBG] HTTP GET / responded 200 in 5465.9319 ms
2024-10-26 09:19:54.513 -04:00 [DBG] HTTP GET / responded 200 in 6799.2390 ms
Ultimately, I want to suppress all the HTTP types (GET, POST, etc.)

Sorry, the comment above didn't retain the original formatting so it is difficult to read.
